# What is the variance of $\ln(x)$ if $x$ has a gamma distribution? $Var(\ln(x))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I know that if $X \sim Gamma(\alpha,\lambda) \implies E(\ln(X))=\psi(\alpha)-\ln(\lambda)$

If $X \sim Gamma(\alpha,1) \implies E(\ln(x))=\psi(\alpha)$

But what happens with $Var(\ln(x))$?

Comment: What kind of parameterization does $X$ have? Also, what kind of function is $\psi (\cdot )$?

Comment: X has a density $f_{X}(x)= \frac{\lambda (\lambda x)^{\alpha-1} e^{- \lambda x}   }{  \Gamma (\alpha ) }  \quad x>0$  and $\psi (\alpha)= \frac{  \Gamma ^{´}(\alpha)   }{ \Gamma (\alpha)    }$.     https://statproofbook.github.io/P/gam-logmean.html

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Feel free to put it into the question field. So $\psi(\alpha)$ is the Digamma function.

Answer (score 2):

Using *Mathematica*, I get a rather curious result:  $$\operatorname{Var}[\log X] = \psi'(\alpha),$$ which apparently does not depend on the rate parameter $\lambda$.  I think this is because the logarithm transforms the rate parameter into a location.

The naive computation would be to write

$$\operatorname{E}[X^k] = \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_{x = -\infty}^\infty x^k e^{-\lambda e^x + \alpha x} \, dx,$$ compute this for $k \in \{1, 2\}$, then simplify.

Another strategy might be to look at the MGF of $Y = \log X$:  clearly $$M_Y(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{t \log X}] = \operatorname{E}[X^t] = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+t)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \lambda^t}.$$  Then computing the derivatives at $t = 0$ gives

$$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \left[\frac{dM_Y}{dt}\right]_{t=0} = \psi(\alpha) - \log \lambda, \\
\operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \left[\frac{d^2 M_Y}{dt^2}\right]_{t=0} = \psi'(\alpha) + (\log \lambda - \psi(\alpha))^2.$$